# Dynamically change object property

Tags: javascript, jquery, jvectormap

I'm using jVectorMaps. I have a map object with a backgroundColor property:

```
map = new jvm.Map({
    container: $('#map'),
    map: "world_mill_en,
    backgroundColor: bgcolor
```

Let's say I declare a global `bgcolor` variable. Then, I change the value of that variable at some point:

```
function changeBGcolor() {
    bgcolor = "yellow";
}
```

The idea is that the jVectorMap background color changes when I change the value of the `bgcolor` variable. So far I was not able to do it.

How can it be done?

Comment: Did you try `map.backgroundColor = 'yellow';` instead?

Comment: There is a `setBackgroundColor()` API method in jVectorMap - Why don't you call that from `changeBGcolor()` - http://jvectormap.com/documentation/javascript-api/jvm-map/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `setBackgroundColor()`. i.e.

```
var bgColor = "red";
var map = new jvm.Map({
  container: $('#map'),
  map: 'world_mill_en',
  backgroundColor: bgColor
});

bgColor = "yellow";

map.setBackgroundColor(bgColor);
```

See the documentation [here](http://jvectormap.com/documentation/javascript-api/jvm-map/#setBackgroundColor) for more information.